# remove hiddenEdgeColor from outlinePass in three.js

Tags: three.js, post-processing

I'm using the [outlinePass](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=outline#webgl_postprocessing_outline) in a three.js project and it has a feature to show the outline of geometry that is behind another in different color, but I don't want this hidden outline at all. How do I remove this?

For example, I don't want the Red outline in below screenshot:

[image: Three.js outline effect]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the hiddenEdgeColor to black

```js
outlinePass.hiddenEdgeColor.set(new Color('black'))
```

Check below screenshot:

[image: Three.js outline pass screenshot with no hidden edge color]

Comment: Tip: you can use the postProcessing package by pmndrs for the [outlineEffect](https://pmndrs.github.io/postprocessing/public/demo/#outline) which gives you more controls

Comment: If you wan't to use black color for visible edge then it won't work as you have to use THREE.customBlending